# Can read receipts be used with emails sent from Apex?

Tags: email, singleemailmessage

Are we able to track if emails sent through Apex code are read/opened?  Sending emails via `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` creates an `EmailMessage` record but does not track when I open it like a email sent through the UI does.

I noticed that there is a value set to the `MessageIdentifier` field for the UI-based email but not the Apex email which I assume is what we need to track the email.